# Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache #Ubuntu #flutter #androidStudio

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu

I'm unable to run my first flutter project, running flutter run throws

> Could not initialize class
> org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

> [ FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 5s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 ]

I use Ubuntu operating system and Android Studio as my IDE. please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your JDK version should be between 8 and 14 .

I solve this problem by going in the file
*my_projet/android/gradle.properties*
and put the command *org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/jdk* your version of the jdk should be between 8 and 14 , if jour jdk version is 14 it will not pass.

Because i am on Ubuntu OS i have written
eg: *org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64*

and after i run my project all works fine